# Why IDBKeyRange.upperBound not working in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, indexeddb

This part of code works fine in Chrome, but in Firefox it returns an empty array! What's the problem?

```
const transaction = DB.transaction(['history_object_store'], 'readonly');
const store = transaction.objectStore('history_object_store');
const index = store.index('id');
const openCursor = index.openCursor(IDBKeyRange.upperBound(50));
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const entries = [];
  openCursor.onsuccess = function(e){
    const cursor = e.target.result;
    if(cursor) {
      entries.push(cursor.value)
    } else {
      resolve(entries);
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have different data loaded in Chrome and Firefox. I don't think there are any bugs in either Chrome's or Firefox's IndexedDB implementations that would lead to such a significant difference for such a simple situation.